# How do I check multiple pandas columns against a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing pandas dataframe, consisting of a country column and market column. I want to check if the countries are assigned to the correct markets. As such I created a dictionary where each country (key) is mapped to the correct markets (values) it can fall within. The structure of the dataframe is below:

[image]

The structure of the dictionary is {'key':['Market 1', 'Market 2', 'Market 3']}. This is because each country has a couple of markets they could belong to.

I would like to write a function, which checks the values in the `Country` column and see if according to the dictionary, the current mapping is correct. So ideally, the desired output would be as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to reference a dictionary across two columns in a function? To confirm, the keys are the country names, and the markets are the values.

I have included code required to make the dataframe:

```
data = {'Country': ['Mexico','Uruguay','Uruguay','Greece','Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Colombia','Colombia','Colombia','Japan','Japan','Brazil','Brazil','Spain','New Zealand'],
        'Market': ['LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','EMEA','ASIA','ASIA','LATAM BRAZIL','LATAM BRAZIL','LATAM CASA','LATAM CASA','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM BRAZIL','LATAM BRAZIL','SOUTHEAST ASIA','SOUTHEAST ASIA']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you include code in the question to create the dataframe?  Showing it as a picture doesn't help people create the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks I have now done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is create tuples and match by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
d = {'Colombia':['LATAM','LATAM CASA'], 'Brazil':['ASIA']}

tups = [(k, x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v]

df['Market Match'] = np.where(df.set_index(['Country','Market']).index.isin(tups),
                              'yes', 'no')
print (df)
        Country          Market Market Match
0        Mexico           LATAM           no
1       Uruguay           LATAM           no
2       Uruguay           LATAM           no
3        Greece            EMEA           no
4        Brazil            ASIA          yes
5        Brazil            ASIA          yes
6        Brazil    LATAM BRAZIL           no
7        Brazil    LATAM BRAZIL           no
8      Colombia      LATAM CASA          yes
9      Colombia      LATAM CASA          yes
10     Colombia           LATAM          yes
11        Japan           LATAM           no
12        Japan           LATAM           no
13       Brazil    LATAM BRAZIL           no
14       Brazil    LATAM BRAZIL           no
15        Spain  SOUTHEAST ASIA           no
16  New Zealand  SOUTHEAST ASIA           no
```

Or by left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True`:

```
d = {'Colombia':['LATAM','LATAM CASA'], 'Brazil':['ASIA']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(k, x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v],
                   columns=['Country','Market']).drop_duplicates()

df['Market Match'] = np.where(df.merge(df1,indicator=True,how='left')['_merge'].eq('both'), 
                              'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the first idea worked a treat. Really helpful for me to learn that. Can you offer some advice on how to paste a nice table like you did in my question?

Answer (score 0):

The following link might help you out in checking if specific strings (e.g. "Markets" are included in your dataframe).

[Check if string contains substring](https://stackabuse.com/python-check-if-string-contains-substring/)

For example:

```
fullstring = "StackAbuse"
substring = "tack"

if substring in fullstring:
  print("Found!")
else:
  print("Not found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['MATCH'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Market'] in your_dictionary[row['Country']], axis=1)
```